# VBA - Looping through string with delimeters

Tags: vba

Hoping someone could help me with this. I have the following string:

RSSRRSSRRR;RSRRSSRSRSRSSRSS;RSRSSS;SRRRSSRR;SSSRS;SRSSRRSRRSSS;SRSSRS;SRSSS;RSSRSRSS;RSRSSRSRRSSS;RSSSS;SRSSS;S/RR/SR/SS/RS/RR.SSSRRS;RSSSS;SRSSS;SSSS;RSSRSRSS;SSRSS;SSRRSRSRSS;SRRSRSSS;RSSSRRSS;SSSS;SSSRS;SRSSS;R/SR/SS/RR/RR/SR/RR/S

This is data from a tennis match. The 'S' represents a point won by the server, 'R' represents a point won by the receiver, ';' represents the end of a game and '.' represents the end of the set. The server in the first game will be Player 1 and the server in the second game will be Player 2. This will swap throughout the match after each game. Given a tie break occurs in the 13th game of a set, the '/' will represent when the serve is switched over to the other player.

I want to get the data into the following format:

Set, Game, Point, PlayerPointID, P1net, P2net,result

1, 1, 1, player2 , -1, +1

1, 1, 2, player1 , 0, 0

1, 1, 3, player1 , +1, -1

...

1, 1, 10, player2, -2,+2, Player2

I've wrote the following code so far:

```
Sub LoopThroughString()

Dim Counter As Integer
Dim MyString As String

MyString = Cells(2, 9)

For Counter = 1 To Len(MyString)

If Mid(MyString, Counter, 1) = "S" Then
Cells(Counter + 1, 16) = Cells(Counter, 16) + 1

ElseIf Mid(MyString, Counter, 1) = "R" Then
Cells(Counter + 1, 16) = Cells(Counter, 16) - 1

End If

Cells(Counter + 1, 17) = -Cells(Counter + 1, 16)

Next

End Sub
```

That basically just loops the string and calculates net values. I'm not sure however how to deal with the delimiters, how it would swap over player 1 and player 2 after each game. Also how I could do a point, game, set count. The point count would need to reset after each game and the game count would reset after each set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split([String], [Delimiter])`to get an Array of strings in which there is a delimiter. for example, your string `RSSRRSSRRR;RSRRSSRSRSRSSRSS;RSRSSS;SRRRSSRR;SSSRS;SRSSRRSRRSSS;SRSSRS;SRSSS;RSSRSRSS;RSRSSRSRRSSS;RSSSS;SRSSS;S/RR/SR/SS/RS/RR.SSSRRS;RSSSS;SRSSS;SSSS;RSSRSRSS;SSRSS;SSRRSRSRSS;SRRSRSSS;RSSSRRSS;SSSS;SSSRS;SRSSS;R/SR/SS/RR/RR/SR/RR/S` when used in the function :

```
Dim MyArray() As String
MyArray = Split(MyString, ";")
```

would be separated as such :

```
RSSRRSSRRR
RSRRSSRSRSRSSRSS
RSRSSS
SRRRSSRR
SSSRS
SRSSRRSRRSSS
SRSSRS
SRSSS
RSSRSRSS
RSRSSRSRRSSS
RSSSS
SRSSS
S/RR/SR/SS/RS/RR.SSSRRS
RSSSS
SRSSS
SSSS
RSSRSRSS
SSRSS
SSRRSRSRSS
SRRSRSSS
RSSSRRSS
SSSS
SSSRS
SRSSS
R/S
R/SS/RR/RR/SR/RR/S
```

Each line being a separate entry in the Array. `MyArray[0]` would then be the first line `RSSRRSSRRR`, which would be the first game, and `MyArray[UBound(MyArray)]` would be the last one `R/SS/RR/RR/SR/RR/S`. `UBound(MyArray)`is the last index of the array provided, which would be equivalent to `25`in this example.

To loop through each entry, you can use a for loop :

```
Dim CurrentGame As Integer
For CurrentGame = 0 to UBound(MyArray)
    For Counter = 0 to Len(MyArray[CurrentGame])
        ' do stuff
        ' like MyArray[CurrentGame][Counter] to get the character "R", "S" or whatever is there.
    Next
Next
```

**NOTE :** I assume you are using the default base 0 indexes from your example, but the *best* practice would be to use `For CurrentGame = LBound(MyArray) '...` instead, where `LBound(MyArray)` gives you the first index of the provided Array.

---

To remember which player is serving, you can create another variable :

```
Dim player1Serving as Boolean
player1Serving = True
```

When you want to switch, simply write :

```
player1Serving = Not player1Serving
```

And when you want to act according to who is serving :

```
If player1Serving Then
    ' Do stuff for Player 1 serving
Else
    ' Do stuff for Player 2 serving
End If
```